# Prepare views for animations, using Autolayout

Tags: ios, animation, autolayout, constraints

I am currently working on an application and I would like to add an animation on a page : View controller 1. In this View Controller 1, I added a container : Container 1. This container should be out of frame when the view will appears and it become visible after a user action.

That's what my view controller 1 in storyboard look like :

[image]

Because I am using auto layout, I would like to play with constraints to hide the container 1 when the View controller 1 will appear. So, I connected the constraint Top of container 1 to my view controller 1 class.

**My First issue - Problem inside**

In this class and in the method viewWillLayoutSubviews, I changed the constant of this contraint to -height of container 1 :

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
        self.container1TopLayout.constant = -self.container1.frame.height
    }
```

I added also a button with its action : showContainer

```
func showContainer(){
        self.container1TopLayout.constant = 0
        UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, animations: { () -> Void in
            self.newCustomServiceContainer.layoutIfNeeded()
        })
    }
```

In this method, I changed the constant to Zero. But the view is doesn't show.

**Second issue - Works correctly**

If in my storyboard, I changed the container 1 position to be already outside the frame before the user taped the action button. When the user taped the button, the container 1 is shown correctly ; I used the same method showContainer

Can you tell me please, what I am doing wrong in my first issue ? Maybe I shouldn't set the constant in viewWillLayoutSubviews ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

In my case I do it like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
   prepareContainer()
}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool)
{
   showContainer()
}
```